# Creating Inherited classes in Packages

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working on an existing project. There is a package of a dozen classes which I need to refactor into base classes and two sets of derived classes.

I tried creating a new package of derived classes, but I get errors when attempting to inherit from a different package.

I don't want to put all the classes in the root of a package, but can't create sub-packages.

How do I arrange this in Netbeans?
It is easy in Visual Studio :-)

Comment: Right click on an existing package and choose "New -> Package".

Comment: I did that, but new package was alongside existing one, not under/within it....

Answer (score 0):

It's so easy in NetBeans too. For example, assuming you have one package and there is a class in it (MyClass1.java):

```
package overstack;
...

public class MyClass1 {

}
```

When you create a new file in the current package, for example, MyClassInherited1.java,  you will have:
    package overstack;
    ...

```
public class MyClassInherited1 {

}
```

No, when you want to move it in other package, you can change the name of package, like here:

```
package overstack.inh;
...

public class MyClassInherited1 {

}
```

you will get a mistake in the code line:     `package overstack.inh;`
Now, clicking the left button of mouse beside this line you will get a proposition to "move class to accessible place". When you click, you will have two packages. NetBeans will execute it automatically. For example, you can look for in the folder:

```
overstack
   MyClass1.java 
overstack.inh
   MyClassInherited1.java
```

Comment: Vasyl, this creates two packages ok, but they are alongside each other. I want one below the other (so that inherited classes are under the base classes, as described in the OP).

Comment: From this reason you find here more: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html
and 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm